# Get ID from Row Number SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
Code     ParentCode     oItem
-----------------------------
A        null           Item 001
B        A              Item 002
C        A              Item 003
D        C              Item 004
E        B              Item 005
```

Now, I want to have the row number then the result should be:

```
Rn        Code     ParentCode     oItem
------------------------------------------
1         A        null           Item 001
2         B        A              Item 002
3         C        A              Item 003
4         D        C              Item 004
5         E        B              Item 005
```

My question is, How's the query to get the following result:

```
Rn        Code     RnParent   ParentCode     oItem
--------------------------------------------------------
1         A        null       null           Item 001
2         B        1          A              Item 002
3         C        1          A              Item 003
4         D        3          C              Item 004
5         E        2          B              Item 005
```

If you see on the result table, `parentcode` is actually the `code` and I need to know the `id` of the `parentcode` base on the `code` of `Rn`.

Please advise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want the `rn` for the `parentcode`.  You can get this with a `join`:

```
with t as (
      select row_number() over (order by code) as rn, t.*
      from t
     )
select t.*, tp.rn as parentrn
from t left join
     t tp
     on t.parentcode = tp.code
```

Comment: yes, you are right. The query above is what I'm looking for. Cheers, :)